# Breakpoint will not currently be hit... Driving me mad

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I am getting the quite common error that the Breakpoint will not currently be hit because the dll is different from the source code.

Normally this is fixed by either rebuilding the solution or if that does not work then by cleaning the solution and if that does not work then I find restarting VS works. In extreme situations I find that I need to clear out the Temporary ASP.NET Files folders to make sure the DLLs are gone and then rebuilding to generate new ones.

However I have done all of that and the new dlls in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folders are all dated at the time of the latest rebuild. Yet still I get this error! How can a new build of the DLL not be the same as the source code it was just built from?

Comment: I assume you have Class library of the dll you are trying to insert breakpoint on,right??

Comment: Yes. It is an Aspx.cs file...

Comment: If so, then remove dll from reference and add the reference of that Class library itself... Then it should work

Comment: I can't remove the reference for an aspx page as there is not one to remove.

Comment: I believe someone had made the DLL of that Class library & then added the reference of that DLL in your application.First remove the DLL only and then try to add reference of that Class library.

Comment: It is an aspx page. It is not a referenced dll. in the older type of web projects dlls are created for each aspx files code behind page.

Comment: Try hitting F12 on any method of that DLL ,see where it lead to as well